# simple graphics package in python 2 or 3

Tags: python, graphics

The following website from the official python tutorial seems to imply that a graphics package is automatically included with an install of Python 3. Beyond being highly skeptical of that, my python 2 does not have the package in question.

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html

Does anyone have any ideas or substitutions for performing simple windowed graphics in python, 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default python "graphics" package is Tkinter

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

In Python 3, it's called "tkinter" - in python 2 it's called "Tkinter". It sometimes includes (depending on your distribution) ttk or tix, which are extensions. It makes direct calls to Tcl, so it's pretty fast at basic operations.

PIL/Pillow is a very standard dependency for any kind of image manipulation. Tkinter basically will only let you work with gif and postscript files

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow

Zelle graphics a beginners graphics program built on tkinter. It is not a serious graphics suite (it's super duper slow), though it can be extremely good for educational purposes. It's meant to accompany his Python book or for self-teaching. Try Turtle as an alternative for teaching purposes, there are a lt of tutorials out there. I don't know which distributions include it, but you can easily download it by googling for it

From your linked page:

> You will just be a user of the graphics.py code, so you do not need to
>   understand the inner workings! It uses all sorts of features of Python
>   that are way beyond these tutorials.

Those features are called Tkinter. I like tk, and this it's pretty easy to use, but that's subjective - take a look and decide for yourself.

If you're looking for more advanced suites or any kind of 3D (tkinter is strictly 2D) (my guess is you aren't for now, but that's okay), try OpenGl for python, or pygame.